# Can't set resolution back to 1080p

Tags: resolution, screen

I have some trouble with upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 from 13.04.
I fixed already multiple problems, but I'm getting stuck with this one. My screen resolution isn't getting higher than 1280x1024. Unity don't work at all, but some time before the upgrade I tried KDE, what I'm using now.

The interface don't have a low resolution, but there is a black border around the screen with every resolution I tried. (While typing this I changed the resolution to 640, and now the buttons are outside of my screen :P) btw, the black borders don't disappear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> but there is a black border around the screen with every resolution I tried

Sounds like "overscan". You can set this from the ati/nVidia admin control center.

ATI:

[image]

nVidia:

[image]

---

Just to make sure the upgrade is not messing up your experience I would advice to do a re-install. My experience is that an install works better then upgrading.